# Instantiate 4 prefabs at 4 locations, shuffled, Unity Engine C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

What I have are 4 platforms that I instantiate at 4 locations. What I want is for the platforms to be shuffled every time. My code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformCreator : MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject[] platforms;
 public Transform[] points;

 private void Start()
 {

     for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
     {
         Instantiate(platforms[i], points[i].position, Quaternion.identity);
     }
 }
```

}

For example the platforms now always spawn in the same order - pink, yellow, blue, purple

I want them to be spawned in different order every time, for example - yellow, blue, purple, pink. I've tried creating an int index with random.range, but I am messing something up

Comment: Could you use int x = Random.Range(0,points.Length) inside your for loop and then points[x].position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the points to a List instead of an array, which will help you to "shuffle" the values. Taking the shuffle function from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt) SO post, you could do something like this:

```
public class PlatformCreator : MonoBehaviour {

 public GameObject[] platforms;
 public List<Transform> points;

 private Random rng; 

 public void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
 {  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
    n--;  
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
    T value = list[k];  
    list[k] = list[n];  
    list[n] = value;  
    }  
 }

 private void Start()
 {
    rng = new Random(); 
    points.Shuffle();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(platforms[i], points[i].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, because points.Length property can't be used with lists. Perhaps I can try with .Count (points.Count)? Same problem with int k = rng.Next(), I am unable to use Next(), receiving an error.

Comment: Yes, sorry. List uses Count, not Length. Updated answer.

Comment: Could you tell me what the error is? I have no way of knowing unless you post it.

Comment: it works, I guess i'll look around more on this shuffling method, it caught my attention. Thanks